# How do I increase GPS module frequency from 1Hz to 10Hz (beitian gps bn880) library GPS Tiny++

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, gps

I do a project related to the GPS module I use the GPS module *(beitian GPS bn880)* connected with Arduino Mega 2560. The module sends data 1Hz so I need speed more but I don't know how to do that. I use *library GPS tiny++*.

**How do I set frequency from 1Hz to 10Hz**

Comment: Does the manual for that GPS receive indicate that it can be set to send data at 10 Hz?

Comment: yes, @PeterBennett. https://rotorgeeks.com/electronics/flight-controllers/beitian-bn-880-gps-compass. The default is setting for 1Hz.

Comment: Why do you think you need a higher speed? Can you interpolate the data yourself to get the intermediate positions?

Comment: Is using timer / counter as a PLL a big deal?

Comment: A lot of the newer gps receivers are supporting the higher update rate for uavs and such.   The documentation should have the ascii string you send to enable this.   What happened when you tried that?  An api/library is overkill.

Comment: what does the nanual say about changing the speed?

Comment: https://youtu.be/TwhCX0c8Xe0
I'm not sure this method works because I never tried it before.
But I will go to try it when I get a USB-UART converter (Still sending from seller).
If it works fine or can increase GPS hertz. I will come here and update you more.

Comment: Many web references. This video MAY help. Factory is on web - asking them may help.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXTtu4n37WI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *appears* to set the rate to either 1 Hz or 10 Hz.
This was from a brief Zipped Word document form [this page](https://www.rcgoing.com/beitian-bn-880-flight-control-gps-module-dual-module-compass-with-cable-for-rc-drone-fpv-racing/) .

[image]

Under the "Configuration files link at the bottom of the page.

https://cdn.shopify.cn/s/files/1/0312/7925/1595/files/BN-880_GPS_Configuration_files.zip?v=1590392430

Answer (score 3):

You usually can't. Things like GPGA messages are simply emitted at a frequency of 1 Hz by such modules.

Not that it would make much sense to try to do so – new location fixes of the same quality as you're currently getting aren't available at much higher rate.

Location modules that offer higher update rates do usually do that through interpolation and *sensor fusion*, i.e. combining the last know locations from GPS, their uncertainty and knowledge from compass and IMUs.

If this modules contained a full IMU, you'd know by the price ;)

However, this thing, from the looks of it is most likely based on the ublox M8030, so `UBX-CFG-RATE` is the command you'd need to set the update rate. Again, don't expect these updates to be more *useful* than your software interpolating between existing updates. Watch the `prStdev` standard deviation field of your fix closely – you'll find that it doesn't usually go down with shorter measurement intervals.

Also note that this almost certainly has significant effect on power consumption!